# How to make socket chat in C++?

Tags: c++, sockets, chat

Does anybody know how to make socket chat in C++ using something like sockets in Java? Is there any way to make ip chat in C++?

Comment: Yes, but you probably won't get a complete solution by asking a question here. I'd look for a tutorial on c++ sockets.

Comment: I would look into boost::asio as a means: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is possible. You could use a library like Boos.Asio which has an example of chat in its documentation : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/posix_chat_client.cpp (client part)

Answer (score 2):

Yes to both of your questions.  The program would work exactly the same in C++ as it does in Java.  You listen on a host/port and send to a host/port.  The only difference will be the language and the API used.